# How to fire a function out of an ajax call in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

This function is changing the input color depending on the ajax response.
If the response is true, the border and text becomes green.
If it's false or there is a empty input, it becomes red.

My problem is, that my `uid_color("green");` call inside the ajax function, doesn't work.

I'm trying to learn the clean way of using Jquery and Javascript without "copy paste" everything.

Why isn't my `uid_color("green");` call working inside the ajax function?

```
myInput.on("input paste",function(){
    var a = $(this);
    var b = a.val();
    var c = b.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g,'');
    a.val(c);
    if(b.length > 0){ /* Check if input empty before ajax call */
        $.ajax({
          url: "/sys/checkuser.sys.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: {uid:b},
          success: function(response){
              /* Change input color if username is free/taken */
              if(response){
                  uid_color("green");
              }else{
                  uid_color("red");
              }
          }
      });//AJAX CALL END
    }else{ //If there is no input or empty don't ajax call.
        uid_color("red");
    }

    function uid_color(x){
        $(".signup-form input[name=uid]").css({"border-color":x,"color":x});
    }
  });
```

Comment: Its out of scope

Comment: I assume `response` should be `true`... But is it a string? Try `console.log(typeof(response));` If it's a string, then change your condition to `if(response=="true"){`

Comment: @Brian: It's not out of scope...

Comment: it's a boolean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It Should work for you

```
myInput.on("input paste",function(){
var a = $(this);
var b = a.val();
var c = b.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g,'');
a.val(c);
if($(this).val().length > 0)
    $.ajax({
      url: "/sys/checkuser.sys.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {uid:b},
      success: function(response){
          if(response){
              uid_color("green");
          }else{
              uid_color("red");
          }
      }
  })
}else{ //If there is no input or empty don't ajax call.
    uid_color("red");
}
function uid_color(x){
    $(".signup-form input[name=uid]").css({"border-color":x,"color":x});
} 

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out the issue.

I was using the `b` variable that was made in the past.

After changing the `if(b.length > 0){` to `if($(this).val().length > 0){` it works like expected :)